# Having issue in my jquery if condition and toggle class method

Tags: jquery

I am creating bike,car wash service at doorstep. For this I ask the customer to tell me when they register for their service if they want me to wash a car or bike. It they choose car then there are further questions that I want to ask. Same for bike. I want to hide the car/bike selection element that the user did not pick.

So far I am using jquery toggle function in the click event of the car/bike choices. If user clicks car I show options for 'full wash' or 'body wash', and if user clicks two wheeler I show the 'full wash' option.

Here is my html form in server. Here is a link to see my rough example: http://vkacademy.in/crystal/.

What I need help with is to make the unselected option from the car/bike choice hide itself. So, user clicks 'car' and 'two-wheeler' is hidden, or same in reverse.

I am still learning so I would be pleased for any assistance and would love to see a working JSFiddle or similar.

My From:

```
<form name="f1" action=""  method="post" enctype=""/>
    <table width="417" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="111">Name</td>
            <td width="48">&nbsp;</td>
            <td></td>
            <td width="244"><input type="text" name="name"  id="name" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Service Rendered</td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" value="car" name="car" id="car"/>Car</span> <br/>
            <p id="car-show" style="display:none"><input type="radio" name="fullwash" value="fullwash" />fullwash <input type="radio" name="bodywash" value="bodywash" />Bodywash</p>
            </td>

            <td><input type="radio" value="twowheeler" name="twowheeler" id="twowheeler"/>Two wheeler <br/><p id="twowheeler-show" style="display:none;"><input type="radio" name="fullwash" value="fullwash" />fullwash</p></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="padding-left:180px;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

My jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit').click(function(){
            a = $('#name');
            if (a.val() == '') {
                alert('Enter the user name');
            }
        });
        $('#car').click(function(){
            $('#car-show').toggle("slide");
        });

        $('#twowheeler').click(function(){
            $('#twowheeler-show').toggle("slide");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: drop the html in your question

Comment: done that, you can see my link http://vkacademy.in/crystal

Comment: There is a slight chance that properly indenting your code will make it easier to read and _fix_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using hide:

```js
  $('#car').click(function() {
    $('#twowheeler-show').hide();
    $('#car-show').toggle("slide");
  });

  $('#twowheeler').click(function() {
    $('#car-show').hide();
    $('#twowheeler-show').toggle("slide");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="f1" action="" method="post" enctype="" />
<table width="417" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="111">Name</td>
    <td width="48">&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
    <td width="244">
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Service Rendered</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" value="car" name="service" id="car" />Car</span>
      <br/>
      <p id="car-show" style="display:none">
        <input type="radio" name="fullwash" value="fullwash" />fullwash
        <input type="radio" name="bodywash" value="bodywash" />Bodywash</p>
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="radio" value="twowheeler" name="service" id="twowheeler" />Two wheeler
      <br/>
      <p id="twowheeler-show" style="display:none;">
        <input type="radio" name="fullwash" value="fullwash" />fullwash</p>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="padding-left:180px;">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: I need another help from you. look the html alignment.if user click car the service rendered caption is moving up and down like wise for two  wheeler also.how to do it properly.I dont know that. another work we have to do here simple for you. if user click car, now full wash  and body wash is coming ,now for full wash the  amount is 400, like wise for body wash the amount is 350 only ,like wise for two wheeler  the full wash amount is 200. kindly help . I know  how to get the php values and db connection that's all rest i will take care. I accepted your answer

Comment: @user3251820 post another question so we can help